# Usar o Xamarin Live Player

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Não estou conseguindo rodar o Xamarin Live Player.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tela do live
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após carregar a tela do live, scaneei o qrcode e inserir no editbox
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após tudo isso, nada acontece